# Extract a List from Hash Map with List Object in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am comparing two HashMaps and extracting keys in first `HashMap` which are not in the second `HashMap`. This is successful. I need to extract the List Value of the missing keys and I am getting null. What am I missing?

```
        ChannelsSingleBundle channelSingle = new ChannelsSingleBundle();
        //get ChannelSingle Map
        HashMap<String, List<ChannelSingle>> singleChannelsMap = channelSingle.getChannelSinglesData();
        //get Dcti map for Channels Single
        DCTIBundle dctiChannel = new DCTIBundle();
        HashMap<String, List<DCTI>> dctiChannelSingleMap = dctiChannel.getChannelSinglesData();
        //Get keys for channels hash
        HashSet<String> unionKeys = new HashSet(singleChannelsMap.keySet());
        unionKeys.addAll(dctiChannelSingleMap.keySet());
        unionKeys.removeAll(dctiChannelSingleMap.keySet());
        System.out.println("Keys in SiingleMap Not in DCTI Map: \n" + unionKeys);//Gives me the coorect keys
        List<ChannelSingle> singles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : unionKeys) {
            singles =  singleChannelsMap.get(key);//Attempt to get List<ChannelSingle> from the key Pair
        }
        for(ChannelSingle single: singles){
            System.out.println(single.getHostRefNumber());
        }
```

**Edit:** As indicated in the comments getHhostRefNumber was indeed Null. Issue now is the List has more Records that it is supposed to have. I need to hahe records equivalent to the number of keys in unionKeys.

Comment: Maybe getHostRefNumber is always giving null because it is null? Try some other attributes

Comment: The assingment `singles = singleChannelsMap.get(key)` doesnt make sense to me. You are looping over all keys, so `singles` only contains the list of the last key. Any chance the last key refers to a `single` that has `hostRefNumber` actually `null`?

Comment: You are right, hostRefNum was null, but the List has more objects than it is supposed to have.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code:

```
        ChannelsSingleBundle channelSingle = new ChannelsSingleBundle();
        //get ChannelSingle Map
        HashMap<String, List<ChannelSingle>> singleChannelsMap = channelSingle.getChannelSinglesData();
        //get Dcti map for Channels Single
        DCTIBundle dctiChannel = new DCTIBundle();
        HashMap<String, List<DCTI>> dctiChannelSingleMap = dctiChannel.getChannelSinglesData();
        //Get keys for channels hash
        HashSet<String> unionKeys = new HashSet(singleChannelsMap.keySet());

        // You do not need to add these keys
        // unionKeys.addAll(dctiChannelSingleMap.keySet());  

        unionKeys.removeAll(dctiChannelSingleMap.keySet());
        System.out.println("Keys in SiingleMap Not in DCTI Map: \n" + unionKeys);//Gives me the coorect keys
        List<ChannelSingle> singles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : unionKeys) {
            singles =  singleChannelsMap.get(key);//Attempt to get List<ChannelSingle> from the key Pair

            for(ChannelSingle single: singles){
                System.out.println(single.getHostRefNumber());
            }
        }
```

Comment: This has no difference with what I have same results. `null` host reference number is actually not the issue because the value is already null from source. Mys issue is that If I have the size of `unionKeys ` as 20, I expect the `List<ChannelSingle>` to be twenty as well as I am fetching the value from `singleChannelsMap` by key.

Comment: You can check that by writing the key in unionKeys for loop. Because if list is empty second for loop does not work(singles loop).